# VB - Set a timer to a windows service every half an hour

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I was able to build a windows service using a timer that executes a function every 30 minutes.

I want that this function to be executed every half an hour, for example. 00:00, 00:30, 01:00.

It can do that now but I have to start the service for example at 14:00 so it follows this pattern (each 30 minutes).

I want to automate this so if I start the service 14:08 it will still execute at 14:30 and not 14:38.

**Extra information:**
This is the function I use for the timer

```
oTimer = New Timer()
oTimer.Interval = 900000
AddHandler oTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimer
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a service and not just windows scheduled tasks?

Comment: It monitors a Website that is developed on ASP.net which the service sends SMS reminders to specific users registered on the platform. I find that making a Windows Service was a good enough, do you find more efficient using windows scheduled tasks?

Comment: Run the timer every minute, see if the current minute is 0 | 30, remembering the last run time to prevent multiple hits

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by setting the timer to every minute. Storing the minutes in a variable and comparing if there where "00" | "30" and then execute! Thanks @AlexK. !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using either a windows scheduled task or a timed scheduling library such as Quartz.Net. That said this requirement is simple enough that you can quickly built this yourself.

Timers have a due time. This is the time it takes until the first tick. After that the interval time will be used. Set the due time to the difference between now and the next execution (in your case `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30 - 08)`).

You can also use a loop:

```
CancellationToken ct = ...; //Signal this token when you want to shut down the service

while (true) {
 var nextDueTime = CalculateDueTime();
 var delay = nextDueTime - DateTime.UtcNow;

 try {
  await Task.Delay(delay, ct);
 }
 catch (OperationCancelledException) {
  break;
 }

 DoWork(ct);
}
```

The loop solution is attractive because it avoid typical timer problems such as concurrent ticks and ticks arriving after the timer was stopped.

Comment: Hmm, you'll have to propose a way for the OP to stop the service properly with that code.